# Adding fields to a JS object by the bracket notation that have special characters

Tags: javascript, object

I have a JS object and I want to add to it a field named "Content-Type".
I add it using the bracket notation as usual.

```
params["Content-Type"] = "application/json"
```

But the problem that I am facing is that, this field gets added as a string. Like this

```
Id: 'de311',
Key: 'Idn71bf9',
'Content-Type': 'image/jpeg'
```

The Content-Type field is being added as a string (with single quotes), which is not accessible I guess.

If the question isn't clear I am happy to explain.

Comment: In your case property `"Content-Type"` of  `params` can be accessed via `params["Content-Type"]`. It cannot be accessed by dot operator like `params.Id` since `Content-Type` is not a valid variable name though.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JavaScript property access: dot notation vs. brackets?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4968406/javascript-property-access-dot-notation-vs-brackets)

Comment: I assume your getting this in the debugger?  Don't worry it's just how it will display it, there is no extra double quotes, it's just how it's been serialised for display.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's perfectly normal and usable - it's just shown as a string in the debugger/console you're using because `Content-Type` isn't a valid variable name, and therefore cannot be displayed as such. You can only access a property called `Content-Type` through bracket notation - other properties, such as `Id`, you could access through either `params.Id` or `params["Id"]` - but due to the nature of the name of the property, and how it can't be used as a valid variable name in JavaScript, it's displayed with quotes.

tl;dr just a visual issue, it's performing exactly how you want it to be.